# How to generate a json with Faker in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

I wanna generate a json with Fake in Ruby on Rails. so I implement the following code and get this output:

```
Faker::Json.shallow_json(width: 4)
```

#Output >>  "{\"Caryl\":\"Herman",\"Guadalupe\":\"Hoyt",\"Broderick":\"Kendra\",\"Martin\":\"Nina\"}"

but I wanna generate a json without any `\`, how do I do to fix it?

Comment: Faker is generating the correct json. If you execute this command on your rails console the output is a string which will be displayed on the console. This display is escaping the quotations. Just try with `print(Faker::Json.shallow_json(width: 4))` and you will see that your output is correct.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I want to save it into database, can I save it like this?

Comment: Of course you can save it to the database. It is after all just a plain string. Just beware that your column has no limit regarding the string length. Just use `:text` type for the column. If you use a database wich supports json storage then you can save this as a json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `JSON.parse()`

For example:

```
irb(main):005:0> JSON.parse Faker::Json.shallow_json(width: 3)
=> {"Jarod"=>"Duane", "Clarence"=>"Abdul", "Rhett"=>"Kennith"}
```

Cheers,
Bojan